# Images loaded from Portable Class Library

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, xamarin, portable-class-library

I have a Windows Store App that has many, many images in it. Further, these images need to be access in multiple projects on multiple plaftorms.

I had created a class library specifically targetting WinRT. This worked well and I was able to access the images using the Uri: `"ms-appx:///MyImageClassLibrary/PathToImage/ImageName.png"`.

The beautiful part of this was that I could have my images sorted by scale similar to how I would in the local assets themselves, via a folder structure such as

```
/Images
    /scale-100
        Image1.png
    /scale-140
        Image1.png
    /scale-180
        Image1.png
    /scale-80
        Image1.png
```

Unfortunately, when I retargeted the library to a PCL (targeting Profile 259), This functionality broke. I now have to manually refer to the same image as `"ms-appx:///MyImageClassLibrary/PathToImage/scale-100/ImageName.png"`.

Is there a way to fix this? Must I target the library to specifically WinRT? <s>If I do target the library to WinRT, can that include Windows Phone 8.1?</s> Will Windows Phone 8.1 be able to process the differently-scaled images?

Based on my intuition, I think I'll likely have to make a different image library for each platform. If this is the case, is there a way to auto-generate or link a subsequent class library targeted at another platform (such as Xamarin.iOS/Xamarin.Android) that copies all files in a given folder of the base project (such as all of them in `scale-100`). I know that I can link files manually, but can I link folders so that any updates to the canonical project are reflected in platform-specific projects?

I will be experimenting more with this process, and will update here with any information I find.

Thanks.

Updates:

The scaling and direct reference work just fine with both Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 targetted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you've figured this out, but for a PCL to support AppX resources, it needs to exclusively target platforms which support AppX resources.  Right now that means Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1.

Comment: Thanks! Currently what I'm researching is a way to portably use SVGs instead. I may try and turn it into a simple all-in-one library if I can get it to work.